# how to set the file path in java

Tags: java, javax.imageio

How to set the file path? I have tried many ways but no luck. There is no error though.

1. `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("test.png"));`
2. `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("/test.png"));`
3. `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("http://localhost:8080/fullscreenSignature/WebContent/VAADIN/images/test.png"));`

I tried all of these but none work for me. I just need to upload image anywhere in server.
Thank you

Comment: IF there is no error means file is found/used. You just need to locate the file.

Comment: There most certainly was an error at (3), and possibly at (2) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by 'set the filepath', but:

> ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("test.png"));

This will write a file called `test.png` in the current directory, provided you have write access, otherwise it will throw an `IOException` saying you don't, or saying what else went wrong.

> ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("/test.png"));

This will write a file called `test.png` in the root directory, provided you have write access, which you probably don't, so it will throw an `IOException.`

> `ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", new File("http://localhost:8080/fullscreenSignature/WebContent/VAADIN/images/test.png"));`

This will throw an IOException because a URL isn't a filename. This is not valid code.

Comment: @BevynQ There is no evidence that he is writing a servlet. If you have an answer of your own I suggest you post it.

Comment: @BevynQ 'Upload to server' suggests nothing about servlets whatsoever. On the contrary, it suggests, rather clearly, that he is writing a client. I have no idea what you may have meant by 'provide more context' either.

Comment: I am writing a servlet. he has done a right guess. and it solved my problem . Thank you all

Comment: So why are you trying to use a URL in a servlet? You're already at the server end.

Comment: yes, this is the problem. so what do you suggest? after your suggestion i changed my file path to this `/WorkspaceWRA/fullscreenSignature/WebContent/VAADIN/images/test.png`. but when i have to run it separately on tomcat it will not find these folders because currently it is running in eclipse workspace. i hope you understand what i am trying to convey. if not then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

> How to set the file path?

Basically, the answer is that you have to use the RIGHT file path.  And that means that you need to understand how filepaths are resolved by the Java libraries.  And that is pretty straight-forward too.

- On a Windows machine, filepath that is prefixed with "X:" for some letter "X" qualifies the path with a specific drive.  (If you leave this off, the application's current drive is assumed.)  The drive is then stripped, and the remainder of the filepath is interpreted as below.
- A filepath that starts with a "/" is resolved relative to the root file system.  So, for example, "/test.png" means a file called "test.png" in the root directory of your system.  (Which probably ought not to work, because that directory should be write-protected!!)
- A filepath that doesn't start with a "/" is resolved relative to the application's current directory.  If you launched the application directly from a shell command prompt, then the current directory will be the shell's current directory.  Otherwise, it is possible that the script or application that launches the java app will *change* the current directory ... before launching.

---

So both "image.png" and "/image.png" are valid filepaths, but they are not necessarily the right ones; i.e. they may not be writeable.  If you want a path that *should be* writeable (on a typical Linux box), try "/tmp/image.png" ... or some-such.  (But again, someone else *might* already have created a file with that pathname ....)

But "http: //localhost:8080/fullscreenSignature/WebContent/VAADIN/images/test.png" is URL and not a filepath ... and won't work.

Comment: This give me a good idea about writing a file path in which i always make a mistake. Thank a lot!